# Por qué no me ejecuta el primer comando de jquery hide()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, async

Tengo una función que llamo al hacer click en un botón, la idea es que esconda una div mientras ejecuta un script PHP por ajax async: false, pero por alguna razón no me ejecuta la linea del hide, el resto todo ok., pero la primera linea no la corre, este es el código:

```
function reSendQRs(ven_id, ven_mailUsuario) {
    $(".modal-resultados").hide(); // esta línea no se ejecuta!!

    ven_mailUsuario = prompt("El mail de notificación se reenviará al siguiente correo:", ven_mailUsuario);
    if (ven_mailUsuario) {
        if (validaEmail(ven_mailUsuario))
            reSendQRsAjax(ven_id, ven_mailUsuario);
        else 
            alert("El correo <b>" + ven_mailUsuario + "</b> no es válido!");
    }
    $(".modal-resultados").show();
}
```

Saludos y Gracias!

Comment: incluir el html

Comment: para cancelar cualquier animacion pendiente `$(".modal-resultados").stop().hide();` para darle tiempo a (no)verse `$(".modal-resultados").delay(200).show();`

Answer (score 1):

Tu tienes la siguiente situación:

```js
function UnaFuncion() {
    console.log("Instrucción 1");
    let p = prompt("mensaje");
    console.log("Instrucción 2");
}
UnaFuncion();
```

Como puedes ver en el ejemplo anterior, los mensajes por consola no se muestran hasta que el `prompt` se esconde, aun cuando existe un `console.log("Instrucción 1");` antes de ese prompt

Esto sucede porque si bien javascript se ejecuta secuencialmente, la actualización a dichos cambios no sucede por cada una de las instrucciones, si no que hay un control interno para renderizar. Entonces, tu primera instrucción `$(".modal-resultados").hide();` está pendiente cuando entra el prompt y le gana a todo y salta en pantalla

La solución es crear un pequeño delay para dar tiempo a renderizar, algo como:

```js
async function UnaFuncion() {
    console.log("Instrucción 1");
    const p = await ShowPromt("Mensaje");
    console.log("Instrucción 2");
}
async function ShowPromt(titulo , texto = ""){
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(()=>r(prompt(titulo,texto)), 100));
}
UnaFuncion();
```

Si no te acomoda que tu función `reSendQRs` (equivalente a "UnaFuncion" en el ejemplo) sea del tipo `async` puede ser entonces:

```js
function UnaFuncion() {
    console.log("Instrucción 1");
    ShowPromt("Mensaje").then(resp => {
      console.log("Instrucción 2", resp);
      /*
      if (resp) {
        if (validaEmail(resp))
            reSendQRsAjax(ven_id, ven_mailUsuario);
        else 
            alert("El correo <b>" + resp + "</b> no es válido!");
        }
       $(".modal-resultados").show();
       */
    });
    
}
async function ShowPromt(titulo , texto = ""){
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(()=>r(prompt(titulo,texto)), 100));
}
UnaFuncion();
```

Comment: Hola amigo, gracias por tu ayuda, pero hice lo que tienes, de hecho al ejecutar el primer código, si se ejecuta el log 1 antes del prompt... y por otro lado, el segundo código hace exactamente lo mismo... no me ha solucionado este código el problema...
Gracias de todas maneras!

Comment: @MagoRola No es así, simplemente presiona el botón "ejecutar" del segundo código y vas a ver que imprime `Instrucción 1`, luego ejecuta el prompt y solo al cerrar el prompt ejecuta `Instrucción 2`

Comment: Si, pero si ejecuas el primero pasa lo mismo... a eso me refiero

Comment: @MagoRola Pero evidentemente, si el primer código es una reducción de lo que  TU tienes, es para mostrar el mismo error pero reemplazando el `.hide()` por un mensaje en consola y quitando esas validaciones que solo aportan ruido al problema. Y desde ahí generar una solución. En el sitio a esto se le llama [MCVE] y es lo que tu deberías haber colocado en tu pregunta desde el inicio

Comment: @MagoRola Recuerda que si la respuesta es correcta puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos